# convert decimal Value to two precision in c#

Tags: c#, decimal

I want decimal value to two precision output like below input,

1. `0`
2. `78.8798`
3. `6`
4. `0.986`

to

1. `0.00`
2. `78.88`
3. `6.00`
4. `0.99`

in c# decimal value to decimal or string.

Comment: `Math.Round` (if you want to round up the value), `.ToString("F2")` (if you want to represent the value)

Comment: `d.ToString("N2")`

Comment: Have you ever tried using Google, or at least looked in the results of similar topics when you wrote the question's title?

Answer (score 6):

One way:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", yourDecimal)
```

Read: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)